# pl/sql - Is there a NVL() for empty rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

With this,

```
set serveroutput on size 900000;
DECLARE
  test VARCHAR(255):=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO test FROM sku WHERE id = 1515;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result:' || test);
END;
```

I'm having the error

```
"no data found"
```

When ID doesn't exist in database.

How can I use something like `nvl()` here, so I can get a default value instead of get an error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**If** appropriate you could do this as an alternative to the more usual NO_DATA_FOUND exception handling:

```
DECLARE
  test VARCHAR(255):=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(id),'default') INTO test FROM sku WHERE id = 1515;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result:' || test);
END;
```

By using MAX(ID) you are sure to get one row back, which will have a NULL when there is no data; you then use NVL in the usual way.

Comment: Maybe too "clever"? - it isn't entirely obvious what the intention is, without a comment or some thinking about it!

Comment: Nothing wrong with being clever, but if a developer tried to sneak this code past my review it'd be sent back...

Answer (score 12):

You could catch the NO_DATA_FOUND Exception

```
DECLARE
  test VARCHAR(255):=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO test FROM sku WHERE id = 1515;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result:' || test);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   dbms_output.put_line ('sorry no data found :(' );
END;
```

More on PL/SQL error handling here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

To my knowledge, there is no such thing as `nvl()` for an empty row in PL/SQL, the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is probably the closest you'll get.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use NVL (or NVL2 or COALESCE, which are similar) here because there's no data on which these functions can operate.  The following will do what you've asked:

```
DECLARE 
  test VARCHAR2(255):=0; 
BEGIN 
  BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO test FROM sku WHERE id = 1515;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      test := '0';
  END;

  dbms_output.put_line('Result:' || test); 
END;
```

but just because something is possible doesn't mean it's a good idea.  The database is trying to warn about something important (specifically, that there's no data which matches your criteria) and this code ignores that warning.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you could move your query to a cursor and fetch from it:

```
DECLARE
test VARCHAR(255):=0;

CURSOR c_test IS
    SELECT id
    FROM sku
    WHERE id = 1515
; 
BEGIN
    OPEN c_test;
    FETCH c_test INTO test;
    IF c_test%NOTFOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('no data found');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('result:' || test);
    END IF;
    CLOSE c_test;
END;
```